# Any thoughts on finding this limit?

Tags: real-analysis

[image: limit]

Only managed to simplify to this one

[image]

Comment: The equivalent formulation $$\exp\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}n\right)\right)$$ might evoke a well known theorem?

Comment: Or, start from your second formula, and apply Sterling equivalent to $(2n)!$ and $n!$.

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{4}{e}$$

Comment: could you specify the well known theorem?

Comment: and sterling equivalent, I have no idea about this notion, googling didn't provide any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $f (n)=e^{\ln (f (n)} $ we have the given limit as $L=e^{\frac {1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{k=n}\ln (1+\frac {k}{n})} $ the power is a well known Riemann sum. So we have $L=e^{\int _0^1 \ln (1+x)dx} $ . Using by parts for integrating we have $L=e^{(x+1)\ln (x+1)-(x+1)|_0^1}=e^{\ln (4)-1}=\frac {4}{e} $

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about this method.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Slick method, definitely beat me on time! +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite your limit as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$$

the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence 
$$\frac{1}{R}= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},$$ provided these two limits exist.

The ratio of two consecutive terms is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&
=\frac{(2(n+1))!n!n^n}{(2n)!(n+1)!(n+1)^{n+1}}
\\
&
=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right )^{-n}
\\
&
=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{-n}
\end{align}
$$
so the given limit is equal to
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\sqrt[n]
{
\left (1+\frac 1n \right ) 
\cdot \ldots \cdot
\left ( 1+\frac n n \right)
}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{-n}=\color{red}{\frac{4}{e}}
$$

Comment: Your patience in writing all this cumbersome things deserves a +1 ;)